# How do I specify the root directory Intern serves for http://localhost:9000?

Tags: intern

I have a project called `delite` where all of its dependencies are at the same level as `delite` itself, rather than in `delite/node_modules`.

Previously, running Intern 3, I specified `baseUrl: ".."` and http://localhost:9000 served one directory above my project, so it could load both `delite` (http://localhost:9000/delite) and its sister projects (ex: http://localhost:9000/dcl).

Is there a way to do the same thing in `Intern 4`?  Currently, http://localhost:9000 serves the contents of the `delite` directory only, so I can't load dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `basePath` config option. The path is relative to the location of the test config (`intern.json`)